# Get the parent of a folder from search results

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

So I searched for a folder in my drive. I found the drive and selected "Open in a new Window".  And now I want to get to the parent folder of that one.

But now the address bar shows `Search Results in D: > New Folder`. There are no "upper" buttons in the window, just back and forward. And `Alt + Up Arrow` goes back to the search results. I don't want the search results, I want the parent folder.

How do I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use "Open folder location" rather than "Open in a new window".

Comment: Yeah, I guess that does it, but it's strange that you have to go back to the search results to achieve this.

Comment: @djeidot, You don’t have to go back to the search results if you hold Shift when you select *Open Folder Location*.

Comment: @Synetech I cannot find such `hold shift and select Open Folder Location` without going back to the search result. This is so silly me.

Comment: @Nam, there is plenty silly when it comes to Windows Search.

Answer (score 5):

*Open folder location* is the ideal, built-in way, but another option is to create your own *Open in New Window* context menu entry as follows:

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\Open New Window]
@="Open New &Window"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\Open New Window\Command]
@="Explorer.exe \"%L\""
```

Create a `.reg` file on your desktop and paste in the above.  Close the file and double click to merge it into your registry (or right click and select "Merge").  The new context menu item should be available immediately.  It will open the folder in the normal file-system hierarchy as opposed to as a child of search results.  You can delete the `.reg` file.

Yet another option is to create an *Open Parent* context menu to allow you to open the parent of a folder:

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\Open Parent]
@="Open &Parent"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\Open Parent\Command]
@="Explorer.exe \"%L\\..\""
```

Comment: thanks but it does not work on windows 10. Any idea about it?

Answer (score 1):

You can right click an item in that folder, and go to `Properties` and see the absolute `Location` path.

Answer (score 0):

Building on [Synetech's answer](https://superuser.com/a/278274/150988):
The "shell\Open parent directory" entry works on Windows 10
after modifying it a little – for recent versions of Windows,
`.reg` files begin with "Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00". 
Also his entry was limiting the context menu to folders.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFilesystemObjects\shell\Open parent directory\command]
@="explorer.exe \"%I\\\\..\\..\\..\\\""
```

As previously explained by Synetech:
Paste that into Notepad, save as .reg and apply and "Open parent directory" will appear in the context menu when clicking on folders or files.

You can also add a string named "Extended" in the "openparent" key so this option only appears while holding down shift.

Comment: Why did you need to add  so many dots and backslashes?

Comment: It's because of escape characters (see https://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php). At the time I didn't quite understand myself so I just pasted the old code into a string in regedit and after exporting as .reg all the slashes are there. Also I had to add the dots because the old code just opened the subdirectory and to my luck it worked after testing around a little.

Comment: Credit goes to Keith Miller to bring the "AllFilesystemObjects" key to my attention, his solution is better, but I updated the post anyways. Change the \"%1\"" in his post to \"%1\\..\\\"" to make it open the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a single entry that works for files & directories:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFilesystemObjects\shell\OpenFSLocation]
@="Open FileSystem Location"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFilesystemObjects\shell\OpenFSLocation\command]
@="explorer.exe /select,\"%1\""
```