# Escape from Windows 7 "Search Results" path

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, desktop-search, windows-desktop-search

When I do a search for files on my system with Windows 7 built-in search, it opens a window with search results.  If ones of the results is a folder and I open it, I go to a location like `ms:query=searchstring\Folder name`, which displays as " ▶ Search Results ▶ Folder name".

Is there any quick way I can convert this into a normal folder view like `C:\Users\Username\Desktop\Folder name`, so that I can navigate up to the parent directory, etc.?  Preferably I'd like to be able to open it in a new window.

Comment: Very similar to https://superuser.com/questions/98717/get-the-parent-of-a-folder-from-search-results

Comment: If for some reason the "open folder location" mentioned in the selected answer is not shown, a useful bypass is to shift-right click on the search result (a folder entry indeed) and select "copy as path", then paste this location into the location bar to open the folder using its full actual path rather than the useless search protocol syntax address.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Easy!  The search results will contain files from various folders.  Right-click the file or folder you are interested in exploring.  In the context menu select "Open File Location" or "Open Folder Location" (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+click to open in a new window).  Explorer will jump there and highlight the file or folder.

A change from XP is that backspace no longer moves up a folder in Explorer.  Backspace acts like a web browser back button now.  But once you are Exploring the file or folder you can click the breadcrumbs in the location box to move up the path.

Comment: Yeah that's what I do already.  :/  It doesn't always show files from the folders, though, and I guess I should have said that I want to open it in a new window.

Comment: Still this the only way to do this and you can also use `Shift` key to open it in new window.

Comment: I don't have Open File Location or Open Folder Location in my context menu. There's some thing that needs to be in the registry for this to exist, and I'm unable to find it right now.

Comment: @Almo If you navigate to the folder in search results, you no longer have this option.  Go back to the search results, right click on the folder, and almost at the bottom of the context menu is the "Open Folder Location" option.

Answer (score 3):

1. Right click, select Properties
2. Click in file path
3. Hit Home, then hit Ctrl-Shift-End to select all of path.
4. Ctrl-C to copy.
5. Paste in path bar.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it doesn't actually work this way. When you right click on a file, the context menu only offers "open folder location" sometimes. It seem to happen randomly. There needs to be a way to tell windows to always show the file path in the search results.

Comment: I think it is always there, but the position may not be where you expect?

Answer (score 1):

If your installation of Win 7 doesn't have `open folder location` or `open file location`, here's a solution:

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/236988-open-file-location-add-remove-context-menu.html

Here's what's in that solution:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; Created by: Shawn Brink
; http://www.sevenforums.com
; Tutorial:  http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/236988-open-file-location-add-remove-context-menu.html

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\lnkfile\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\OpenContainingFolderMenu]
@="{37ea3a21-7493-4208-a011-7f9ea79ce9f5}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\LibraryLocation\ShellEx\ContextMenuHandlers\OpenContainingFolderMenu]
@="{37ea3a21-7493-4208-a011-7f9ea79ce9f5}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Results\ShellEx\ContextMenuHandlers\OpenContainingFolderMenu]
@="{37ea3a21-7493-4208-a011-7f9ea79ce9f5}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.symlink\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\OpenContainingFolderMenu]
@="{37ea3a21-7493-4208-a011-7f9ea79ce9f5}"
```