# Windows break out of search mode to acquire address

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, windows-search

I was working on setting an environment variable in windows. I didn't know where the file was that I wanted to find so I used the search bar in windows. But once I found the file I was unable to copy the address. See:

[image]

The problem is that any attempt to highlight the address, even after clicking into the folder, still has the search information in it. How do I break out of this "search" mode and back to regular finder mode?

To confirm, copy address, and copy address as text, both do not yield the address as they should but ALSO yield the same search text:

```
search-ms:displayname=Search%20Results%20in%20Computer&crumb=location:%3A%3A{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}\Vim

search-ms:displayname=Search%20Results%20in%20Computer&crumb=location:%3A%3A{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}\Vim
```

Whereas I would expect they output the proper path

```
C://Program files (x86)//vim//
```

Updates: when left/right clicking:

[image]

Comment: Click _anything_ (_Computer_ item?) in the left pane or right click _any_ item in right pane and select  `open file location`.

Comment: I can't seem to find "open file location". I added it to the question body, right clicks do not yield an open file locaiton option. They do yield an "open" option at the top, but when I use that the problem persists (the search bar is still in URL). Also left click open, doesn't help either (same problem).

Comment: Also right clicking on computer fixes the search problem, but sends me to computer (so I lose the search). And right clicking yields an identical list of options as what I have attached to the question

Comment: Right click `vim74` and select `open folder location` and then either press {enter} or double click `vim74` in right pane. Sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: I don't see any open folder location option on the screen after the right click, would you be able to post an answer with a screen shot? then we can continue in the comments underneath that :).

Comment: Compare this answer: [If your installation of Win 7 doesn't have open folder location or open file location](http://superuser.com/a/919703/376602)